# Automating tasks on a server

Tags: php, json, apache, automation

I'm looking to automate some tasks on a server, it involves:

Analyzing excel sheets and updating a JSON file as the output.

My server knowledge is pretty basic, I've used xampp to run an apache server and PHP, databases etc.

But I can't find anywhere on the web the approach to what I need.

Basically, I just want my server to analyze a couple of excel sheets once a day and generate a json feed.

Please guide me in the right direction, i´ve been googling for hours, perhaps I´m not using the right words!

Comment: Do a google search for "XAMPP cron jobs"

Comment: `My server knowledge is pretty basic` -> learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a cron job on your server to perform specific tasks on specified time period. You can give a URL to the fine while setting up a cron and add the time when you want to execute it.

Comment: @SolórzanoIgnacio If the answer satisfies you, could you mark it done?